# Reply on same interface from which the request came?

Tags: routing, ip-routing, ubuntu-22.04

Virtual machine with two network interfaces. Both interfaces have a default gateway. One is connected to the Intranet. The other is connected to the Internet.

```
                                      Host
              +---------+      +----------------+
Intranet <--> | Gateway | <--> |     ens001     |
              +---------+      |  10.20.50.100  |
                               |----------------|
                               |     ens104     |      +---------+        
                               |  10.25.40.200  | <--> | Gateway | <--> Internet
                               +----------------+      +---------+
```

The connection doesn't work properly. And, outgoing traffic always goes through interface ens104.

Routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens104
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens001
10.20.50.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 ens001
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens001
10.25.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens104
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens104
```

How can the Linux TCP/IP stack be configured to respond on the same interface as the request?

Comment: for my personal, to less information, on which condition should be used the other gateway. please update the question by reading [ask]

Comment: As the left side is "Intranet" and not "Internet", then no there shouldn't be two default gateways. But just two gateways, only one of them with the default route. As for the other, you have to describe what is "Intranet".

Comment: "The routing table is wrong".

Comment: "The weak host model implies that the outgoing traffic will be directed to the first interface listed in the routing table that matches the destination IP address or selected gateway if the destination is not directly reachable, regardless of the source IP address." https://copyprogramming.com/howto/why-does-linux-network-traffic-only-go-through-eth0 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258810/linux-source-routing-strong-end-system-model-strong-host-model